70s Thriller Sci-Fi Movie Featuring Man With Enhanced Brain
This is either a 70s or possibly early 80s Sci-Fi/ Thriller movie (but set in contemporary time), most likely a made-for-TV movie, definitely American, where an ordinary man has an accident of some sort at the start of the film and this makes him smarter. The key "superpower" he gets as a result is that he now has access to everything he has ever seen or heard. 
Our dark-haired hero is aged 25-35 and spends a lot of the movie running about in a black leather jacket, and all the collars in this film are long and pointy, which is what dates it in my mind.
At one point our hero is with a woman and determines chemical compounds on an outdoor spot by looking at what height they burn. The last thing he identifies is blood.
I saw this movie on British TV in 1989. It was showing its age even then, and my best guess for its production is mid 70s (pointy collar times, but def. not he 60s). Any help will be much appreciated, it's driving me nuts!

Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. If you have added any of these details, very good. However, if you recall something, be it as the smallest detail, feel free to edit your question. Also see How to Ask Identify-this-X questions. Thank you.

Could it be Charly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charly
September 23, 1968 is release date.
Charly Gordon (Cliff Robertson), an intellectually disabled man with a strong desire to make himself smarter, has been attending night school for two years where he has been taught by Alice Kinnian (Claire Bloom) to read and write. However, his spelling remains poor and he is even unable to spell his own name.
Alice takes Charly to the "Nemur-Straus" clinic run by Dr. Richard Nemur and Dr. Anna Straus. Nemur and Straus have been increasing the intelligence of laboratory mice with a new surgical procedure and are looking for a human test subject. As part of a series of tests to ascertain Charly's suitability for the procedure, he is made to race Algernon, one of the laboratory mice. Algernon physically runs through a maze while Charly uses a pencil to trace his way through a diagram of the same maze. Charly is disappointed that he consistently loses the races. Nevertheless, he is given the experimental surgery.
After the surgery, Charly is initially angered that he is not immediately smarter than he was before and still loses in races against Algernon. Eventually, however, he beats Algernon in a race and then his intelligence starts increasing rapidly. Alice continues to teach him, but he soon surpasses her. Charly's co-workers also try to tease him by making him work on a machine that they believe he will not be able to work. When Charly shows he can work the machine, his co-workers are not pleased with the fact that he is now intelligent and cannot be teased anymore. They sign a petition against him and he loses his job at the bakery. Charly also starts staring at Alice's bottom and breasts as well as drawing and painting abstract nude figures of her. He also questions whether Alice loves her fiancé. One night, Charly follows Alice back to her apartment and sexually assaults her, pulling her to the floor and kissing her forcefully until she breaks free by slapping him.

I'm a huge fan of the novel Flowers For Algernon, and very grateful to hear about this adaptation since I haven't seen that one yet, only the Matthew Modine version (good film, bad score). But sadly, that's not my movie! I should have mentioned that it's a THRILLER and will edit my question to avoid further confusion. Nice try, though, thanks!
